# WordPress run on PHP's build on server

Tags: php, wordpress, console, server

I am thinking that as we can use PHP's built-in server to run Laravel/Symfony and other frameworks locally, Isn't it possible to run WordPress locally using PHP's built-in server?

I am trying to run PHP built-in server for WordPress and Simply try to run the server indicating the document root to the WordPress `index.php`,

```
php -S localhost:2000 index.php
```

But It's not working and showing some errors like `The localhost page isn’t working` and similar.

Did anyone try this? There need any more tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify index.php on the command line. Run the server like:
`php -S localhost:9000`

You should be in the root directory of wordpress when running this command. Or Specify the webroot with the -t flag:

`php -S localhost:9000 -t <Directory Containing Wordpress>`